# Getting the "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack-overflow

I am getting this JavaScript error in Chrome:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   [http://localhost:5545/assets/js/jquery.min.js:2]

With this `click` event:

```
$('.accept-answer-button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').replace('answer_', ''),
        b = this;
    if ($('.accepted').length > 0) $('.accepted').click();
    AP.AcceptAnswer(id, $(b));
});​
```

The code for `AP.AcceptAnswer()` is:

```
AP.AcceptAnswer = function(a, o) {
    $.getJSON('/assets/ajax/accept-answer', {
        qid: qid,
        answer: a
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            if (data.type == 'accepted') {
                var title = o.attr('data-unaccept-title').replace('{t}', data.time);
                o.addClass('accepted').attr('title', title);
            }
            else if (data.type == 'unaccepted') {
                var title = o.attr('data-accept-title').replace('{t}', data.time);
                o.removeClass('accepted').attr('title', title);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert(data.error);
        }
    });
}; // end AP.AcceptAnswer()​
```

I am doing `$('.accepted').click();` just to unaccept the currently accepted answer (if there is one) when the user would like to accept another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the classes `.accepted` and `.accept-answer-button` aren't pointing to the same element? If they are you are **recursively** firing a click event when you do this:

```
$('.accepted').click();
```

If `$('.accepted').length > 0` is always true.

Comment: There's only one element with the `.accepted` class but two elements have the `.accept-answer-button` class (because there are two answers). Would this still be recursively firing the click event?

Comment: You're right. I was recursively firing the click event. I added an if statement in the `click` event to check if the button has the `.accepted` class. If it does, then I _don't_ check for `.accepted` and fire the click event on it. Now it works. Thanks!